# What is involved in adding my own event to WPF controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling, touch

I'm constantly having to use TouchDown/TouchUp events here in my WPF project to detect a 'double-tap'; sometimes on a listbox, sometimes a button, sometimes a telerik control. How would I go about adding a DoubleTap event and event handler to these controls? Too big of a job?

Comment: Look at the code in: http://touch.codeplex.com/ It shows you how to add behaviors to support gestures like double tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class that is constructed with a reference to the control and a delegate function. (Please forgive my not perfect syntax [if it isn't perfect], I am typing this from memory)

```
public class DoubleTap {
    delegate void ActionFunction();
    Control ReferencedControl;
    public DoubleTap ( ref Control referencedControl , delegate actionFunction ) {
        ActionFunction = actionFunction;
        ReferencedControl = referencedControl;
        // apply TouchDown and TouchUp event handlers to ReferencedControl
    }
    // Put your TouchDown and TouchUp functions for testing the double tap here
    // when double tap tests as true then call ActionFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use behaviors for this.This will include creating derived type from [System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726531%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) and override OnAttached method for TouchDown/TouchUp.

See [WPF Tutorial | Behaviors](http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html) and [Introduction to Attached Behaviors in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF) for how to implement behaviors.